# Java send email through gmail, sometimes works sometimes hang

Tags: spring, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am sending email by Gmail through my web app.

However, sometimes it is working fine but sometimes it just stop without any message.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

In my spring AppConfig.java

```
@Bean
    public JavaMailSender getMailSender(){
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);
        mailSender.setUsername("my email from");
        mailSender.setPassword("my email password");

        Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        //javaMailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        javaMailProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");

        mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
        return mailSender;
    }
```

In my mailService.java

```
public void sendEmailWithTemplate(Activity activity, Object object) {
        Member member = (Member) object;

        MimeMessagePreparator verificationEmail = getEmailFromActivity(activity, member);

        try {
            mailSender.send(verificationEmail);
            System.out.println("Message sent.............................");
        } catch (MailException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

private MimeMessagePreparator getEmailFromActivity(final Activity activity, final Member member) {

        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

                helper.setSubject(activity.getActivity_subject());
                helper.setFrom("my from email");
                helper.setTo(member.getEmail());

                String mailContent = activity.getActivity_content();

                helper.setText(mailContent, true);


            }
        };
        return preparator;
    }
```

Sometimes its working fine and I will be able to send the mail, but sometime is just stop for more than 20 minutes at:

```
DEBUG SMTP: enable SASL
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
```

Comment: Sounds like a networking problem.  Do you have a firewall or anti-virus?  Try setting a [connection timeout](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.connectiontimeout).

Comment: Hi, ya, but I turn off firewall and anti-virus but still same. However its okay because I try another method from other post and its working fine right now. But too bad I can't search back the post

Comment: Exactly what did you change to make it work?

Comment: I post my method below, please check @BillShannon

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I get from other post, but I can't look back the post.
Activity is one of my object storing the subject and content.

```
public void sendEmailWithActivity(Activity activity, Object object, String path) {
        try {
            Member member = (Member) object;
            String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            String username = "email";
            String password = "password";
            String body = activity.getActivity_content();
            String name = activity.getActivity_name();
            String subject = activity.getActivity_subject();=


            //Set the properties
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
            // Set the session here
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            // set the message content here
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setContent(body, "text/html");
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(member.getEmail()));
            Transport t = session.getTransport("smtps");

            t.connect(host, username, password);
            t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            t.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }

    }
```

Comment: I see you've replaced use of the Spring API with direct use of the JavaMail API.  You don't need to set the `mail.smtps.auth` property because you're calling the connect method with the username and password explicitly.  Also, you should [replace Session.getDefaultInstance with Session.getInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: @BillShannon Do you have any idea why the Spring API work sometimes but sometimes not? I have allowed the service in firewall too. But with the JavaMail API it works every time.

Comment: Nope.  It would require debugging.  But that seems like a job for the Spring people.